# Cast Binding Path so it recognises ViewModel property at Design-Time

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, binding-context

Ok this is more of an annoyance than a problem. There is no error

**Page**

```
<ContentPage
   ...
   x:Name="This"
   //hack to have typed xaml at design-time
   BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Static viewModels:ViewModelLocator.ChooseTargetLocationVm}}"
```

**SubView**

```
<views:ProductStandardView
    ...
    BindingContext="{Binding Product}">
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger
            Binding="{Binding Path=BindingContext.IsVacate, Source={x:Reference This}}"
            TargetType="Grid"
            Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource WarningColor}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
```

When *Binding* to `BindingContext` from the *Source* *Reference* of `This`, i get a XAML "warning"

> Cannot resolve property 'IsVacate' in data context of type 'object'

```
Binding="{Binding Path=BindingContext.IsVacate, Source={x:Reference This}}"
```

Obviously the *BindingContext* is an *object* and untyped. **However the above code compiles and works**

What i want to do is cast it, firstly because i have OCD, however mainly because its easy to spot real problems on the IDE page channel bar

The following seems logical but doesn't work

```
Binding="{Binding Path=BindingContext.(viewModels:ChooseTargetLocationVm.IsVacate), 
                  Source={x:Reference This}}"
```

In the output i get

> [0:] Binding: '(`viewModels:ChooseTargetLocationVm`' property not
>   found on
>   '`Inhouse.Mobile.Standard.ViewModels.ChooseTargetLocationVm`', target
>   property: '`Inhouse.Mobile.Standard.Views.ProductStandardView.Bound`'

I understand the error, yet how else would i cast?

---

And just for stupidity, obviously the following wont compile

```
Binding="{Binding Path=((viewModels:ChooseTargetLocationVm)BindingContext).IsVacate, Source={x:Reference This}}"
```

---

So is there a way to cast a *BindingContext* to a *ViewModel* so any *SubProperty* references are typed at design time?

**Update**

This is relevant for inside a `DataTemplate` or in this case when the control has its own `BindingContext` which is why i need to use the `Source={x:Reference This}` to target the page.

**Note** : `<ContentPage.BindingContext>` doesn't work for me as i'm using prism and unity and it doesn't seem to play with well a default constructor on initial tests, though i might play around with this some more

Comment: How about just setting the binding path to the desired property `Path=IsVacate`?

Comment: @Nkosi Ahh sorry if i wasn't clear, this is a datatemplate in in a listview, so i need to reference the page and binding to a property in its viewmodel , ill update the question to be more specific

Comment: Property suggestions are presented (in VS 15.7) with the syntax <ContentPage.BindingContext><viewModels:MyViewModel/></ContentPage.BindingContext>, but probably not members of properties or inside a datatemplate (still in VS 15.7 (https://blog.xamarin.com/new-xamarin-forms-xaml-intellisense-visual-studio-2017/) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extend `ContentPage` to create a generic type - that supports type parameter for view-model - which in turn can be used in `Binding` markup extension.

Although it may not give you intellisense like support - but should definitely remove the warning for you.

For e.g.:

```
/// <summary>
/// Create a base page with generic support
/// </summary>
public class ContentPage<T> : ContentPage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This property basically type-casts the BindingContext to expected view-model type
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The view model.</value>
    public T ViewModel { get { return (BindingContext != null) ? (T)BindingContext : default(T); } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ensure ViewModel property change is raised when BindingContext changes
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();

        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ViewModel));
    }
}
```

### Sample usage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<l:ContentPage 
    ...
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:SampleApp" 
    x:TypeArguments="l:ThisPageViewModel"
    x:Name="This"
    x:Class="SampleApp.SampleAppPage">

    ...                            
         <Label Text="{Binding ViewModel.PropA, Source={x:Reference This}}" />
    ...
</l:ContentPage>
```

**Code-behind**

```
public partial class SampleAppPage : ContentPage<ThisPageViewModel>
{
    public SampleAppPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new ThisPageViewModel();
    }
}
```

**View model**

```
/// <summary>
/// Just a sample viewmodel with properties
/// </summary>
public class ThisPageViewModel
{
    public string PropA { get; } = "PropA";
    public string PropB { get; } = "PropB";
    public string PropC { get; } = "PropC";

    public string[] Items { get; } = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };
}
```